# WordPress JWT - Error authentification (401)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, jwt

I just discovered WordPress a short time ago, and encounter some problems when using JWT with a custom endpoint.

Indeed, after having correctly configured my API and JWT, I encounter an authentication problem during my AJAX request.

What seems strange to me is that I have no problem using Postman. So I think it's a WordPress configuration problem ...

Here is an overview of my code, which I have shortened, and made as clear as possible for the occasion.

**Configuration of JWT:**

**(.htaccess)**

```
...
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]
</IfModule>
...
```

**(wp-config.php)**

```
...
define('JWT_AUTH_SECRET_KEY', 'secretKey...');
define('JWT_AUTH_CORS_ENABLE', true);
...
```

**Ajax (In my plugin folder)**

```
jQuery.ajax({
        url: url + '/wp-json/test/v1/test_users' + order,
        type: 'GET',
        headers: 
        {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer myToken...'
        },

        success: function(data) {
            alert('success');
        },

        error : function(data) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(data));
        }
    });
```

**Endpoint (In my child theme)**

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
            register_rest_route( 'test/v1', '/test_users', array(
                'methods' => 'GET',
                'callback' => array($this, 'get_users'),
                'permission_callback' => function () {
                    return Routes::test_authorized(5);
                }
            ) );
        });

public static function test_authorized($group)
{
    global $wpdb;
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();

    if (empty($current_user))
        return false;

    $user = ...

       ...

    if (empty($user) || $user == null || $user->test_group > $group)
        return false;

    return true;
}
```

**nonce**

```
add_action('rest_api_init', function () {
            add_filter('jwt_auth_token_before_dispatch', function ($data, $user) {
            // Tells wordpress the user is authenticated
            wp_set_current_user($user->ID);
            $data['nonce'] = wp_create_nonce('wp_rest');
            return $data;
            }, 10, 2);
        });
```

Thank you !

EDIT :

**Error message :**

> {"readyState":4,"responseText":"{"code":"rest_forbidden","message":"Sorry,
>   you are not allowed to do
>   that.","data":{"status":401}}","status":401,"statusText":"Unauthorized"}

I just did a test :

```
public static function test_authorized($group)
{
        [...]

        echo '----------' . $current_user->user_nicename . '--------';

        [...]
}
```

And here is the answer :

> {"readyState":4,"responseText":"---------------------------{"code":"rest_forbidden","message":"Sorry,
>   you are not allowed to do
>   that.","data":{"status":401}}","status":401,"statusText":"Unauthorized"}

So I have the impression that the user is not well set when adding the filter. But why does it work on postman ....?

Comment: Would you mind telling us what the problem is? Is there any error message given?

Comment: `{"readyState":4,"responseText":"{"code":"rest_forbidden","message":"Sorry, you are not allowed to do that.","data":{"status":401}}","status":401,"statusText":"Unauthorized"}`

Comment: I just did a test :

`public static function test_authorized($group)
 {
  global $wpdb;
  $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
  
  echo '----------' . $current_user->user_nicename . '--------';
  
               [...]
 }`

And here is the answer :

`{"readyState":4,"responseText":"................{"code":"rest_forbidden","message":"Sorry, you are not allowed to do that.","data":{"status":401}}","status":401,"statusText":"Unauthorized"}`

So I have the impression that the user is not well set when adding the filter. But why does it work on postman ....?

Comment: @AlinoëRuntz click on edit to put the error message and any additional info into your question.

Answer (score 2):

Please make sure that you have added below code in you htaccess file

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]
SetEnvIf Authorization "(.*)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1
```